# File Download through Rest Call after querying from MongoDB and creating a csv Through Java

Tags: mongodb-java, mongoexport, mongodb-rest

Mongo Collection has the following data...

```
{ "_id" : "Sims", "count" : 32 }
{ "_id" : "Autumn", "count" : 35 }
{ "_id" : "Becker", "count" : 35 }
{ "_id" : "Cecile", "count" : 40 }
{ "_id" : "Poole", "count" : 32 }
{ "_id" : "Nanette", "count" : 31 }
```

Through rest call, taking id from the url,can i query From mongo DB through Java and  Download the csv file containing all the data of id1?
What can be the API's used for File Download.And the file is not located on some server.

Flow should be as follows:

```
http://localhost:8080/Application/Poole
```

Now my Java code would be something like

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(“localhost”,27017);
        MongoDatabase mongoDatabase = mongoClient.getDatabase(test123);

        MongoCollection mongoCollection = mongoDatabase.getCollection(testcoll);

mongoCollection.find(id);
```

The query returned should write the result to CSV File and the file download should happen.
Also any ApI to convert the result of Mongo query result to csv file

Answer (score 0):

Best solution could be that you use the plugin for saving a file and write a custom code which will convert you JSON data (coming from Mongodb collection) to csv. I have made a code for myself but its on Javascript. Let me know if you need it. Thanks.